# How to call these api value in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

Here is my api 
http://ec2-52-66-70-148.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/api/v1/qa/answer/health/1

Their output JSON:

```
{"code":"S-QA501","message":"Success","result":[{"_id":"57f1f222fed49a24e02d5842","title":"hiw to improve netabilism?","revision":null,"author":{"userid":"","name":"","imageurl":"","followers":0,"singlelinedesc":""},"postdatetime":"2016-10-03T05:52:34.256Z","status":"","qatags":null,"category":"","answer":null,"answercount":0,"qaviewscount":4,"popularcount":0}]}
```

I try this angular js for finding their id but it does not work at all:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x._id }}</td>

  </tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://ec2-52-66-70-148.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/api/v1/qa/answer/health/1")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.result;});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Defines 'It not work at all' ? Any errors ?

Comment: yes it show blank bt i want to show their _id

Comment: Show us the error then... Does it get inside the success function ? If not write an error function and see the error

Comment: when i chek in console it show anjulartest.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ec2-52-66-70-148.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/api/v1/qa/answer/health/1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on serer-side.

As you said in the comments an error is shown in the console when calling the API

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load ec2-52-66-70-148.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/api/v‌​1/…. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

This is a CORS error. This means that your API does not allow you to call it.

## Option 1

You have access to the server code and then you can modify it and add the necessary CORS

## Option 2

You do not have access to the server code and then there is nothing you can do. You should contact the server admin if you are linked to them or find another API.

Answer (score 0):

First of all for accessing amazonaws server you need **bucket_name, access_key, and secret_key**

Please make sure you have all three credential, so that you can proceed further..